# How define very large 2D array in C (like 1000*1000)

Tags: c, arrays, string, visual-studio, int

what is the solution?
Do you know a way to help me create a large array?
I used the (int) statement that creates a 100 * 100 array without problems, while this command for the 1000 * 1000 array causes error code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define true 1

int main()
{
    int i, j;

    int a[1000][1000];
    int b[1000][1000];
    int x = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &b[i]);
        scanf_s("%c", &ch);
        if (ch !='-')
        {
            x = (i+1);
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d\n\n", x);

    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(b[i]); j++)
        {
            printf("%d\n\n", b[i][j]);
        }
    }


return 0;
}
```

Comment: "causes error code" What error? You need to show the problem to get help. What compiler are you using? What platform is this for? Those arrays each have 1000000 elements, so they're going to be on the order of megabytes in size. If this is for a microcontroller, that's not going to fit.

Comment: You allocate your `int a[1000][1000]` _on the stack_. You can quickly run out of stack space. Better to allocate it globally or by using `malloc`.

Comment: `scanf_s` requires the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or [. The buffer size is passed as _an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable_. You do not do that. Probably, if you turn on __warnings__ of your compiler, it will warn you.

Comment: And `ch` is not declared.

Comment: dear Paul Ogilvie , when i use malloc to create 2D array i recieve stackoverflow Message from visual studio . what should i do ?
@PaulOgilvie

Comment: `j < strlen(b[i])` is nonsense because `b[i]` is an int and as such has no string length.

Comment: Use `malloc`, not `malloca`. And that can't give you a stack overflow.

Comment: Come to think of it, `scanf_s("%d", &b[i]);` is also quite very wrong because `b[i]` is _two_ dimensional array.

Comment: (ch is not declared) is my another problem : i wan to recive Numbers with different number of digits and By character '-' separated until user enter .
this code is my idea and wrong . can you help me please ?
@PaulOgilvie

Comment: Use `scanf` to read the numbers. Use a space as separator (much easier than `-`), until you read an empty line.

Comment: the code that i need is :

input : 112233-244-32333-244
output: 123-24-323-24

input :133-1213
output :13-1213

Can you please correct my code, I need it very much now.
@PaulOgilvie

Comment: i don;t want to use - , i have to :-(
@PaulOgilvie

Comment: Use `fgets` to read a line, then a loop with `atoi`, skipping characters until after the next `-` or `\n`.

Comment: i dont khow how , Can you please correct my code, I need it very much now?
@PaulOgilvie

Comment: Look them up in the documentation and try it. That's how to learn.

Comment: ok , @PaulOgilvie please see my new code

Comment: compile the program as 64 bit not 32bit. 32 bit version as 2GB heap limit (Microsoft compiler)

Answer (score 0):

Compile the program as x64 not x86. In x86 heap size (microsoft compiler is limited to 2GB).

[image]

Choose x64

Comment: how ? i don't khow how to do ?

Comment: @MostafaBorhani see my answer GLUM